# Can't see keyboard input after "killall python"

Tags: python, linux, shell, python-2.7, busybox

I am working on an embedded Busybox system running Python 2.7.

Whenever I kill Python using

```
killall python
```

while I run an interactive python shell future instances of the interactive python shell break for that session.

So e.g. I have an ssh connection to the device that is currently running the python shell. Now I use "killall python" from another shell. The shell on the first ssh connection closes (as expected) with the message "Terminated". So far this is all expected.

Now I use the "python" command again in the same shell where I had the last python shell. Now I get abnormal behaviour in the sense that none of my input is displayed.

So e.g. if I normally enter "print('test')" I see this:

```
>>> print('test')
test
>>>
```

If I do the same after killing python I see this:

```
>>> test
>>>
```

So as you see, my input ("print('test')\n") is not displayed as expected.
All outputs from the program are visible, though.

To fix this I have to close the connection (e.g. the ssh connection) and start it again.
It only affects connections that had the python shell running while I used the killall-command. So if there are multiple ssh connections only the ones are affected that had python running at the time of the killall-command.

It doesn't matter if I use "killall" or just "kill [PID]", the result is the same.

Does anyone know what causes this and how to fix this?

Comment: Don't `killall python` but `kill PID`.

Comment: Same story here. Tried that right now, there is no difference whether I use killall or kill

Comment: What was the downvote for?

Comment: BTW -- there's nothing specific to the Python interpreter here. You wouldn't see input on anything else that depends on local echo inside the same session -- bash, etc -- once you get your terminal into a state where local echo is turned off.

Comment: Now, *how* you get local echo turned off is an interesting question. Any kind of call for password input could do that, if you send the SIGTERM during such input (preventing it from turning local echo back on when done). (Some well-behaved programs will try to turn local echo back on if they're TERM'd out during a password prompt, but if you were to be sending, say, a SIGKILL, then they wouldn't have the opportunity for that or any other cleanup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Local echo" -- printing input you type -- is a toggleable terminal setting. You're getting your terminal into a state where it's turned off. (This can easily happen if a program exits while prompting for password input, which is a particular circumstance where it's common to turn off local echo for security reasons).

To completely reset your terminal to a known-good state, run `stty sane` before restarting Python. To only enable local echo, run `stty echo`.